# Including a scrollable layout under a toolbar

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-appbarlayout

In my activity layout file, I'm defining an `AppBarLayout` with a `Toolbar` in it. Then I'm including the main content of that `Activity` from another file, which should be scrollable.

I can scroll the content of the second activity, however, when scrolling to the bottom, some part of the layout is just cut out. (I can't see the bottom buttons). I don't want the `Toolbar` to be scrollable, only the content.

**activity_first:**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#FFF"
    tools:context=".StartScreens.Home.HomeScreens.FirstActivity"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout 
        android:id="@+id/Activity_AppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include android:id="@+id/Activity_Toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include android:id="@+id/Activity_First_Content_Include"
        layout="@layout/activity_first_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/Activity_AppBar"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**activity_first_content**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFF"
        tools:context=".StartScreens.Home.HomeScreens.FirstActivity">

        <!-- Content -->

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText_Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:ems="10" />

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/Activity_RatingBar_Stars"
            android:layout_width="241dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/TextView_Stars"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/EditText_Title"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp" />

        <!-- A lot more content -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button_Clear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="Clear"
            android:text="@string/clear"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.775"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/Button_Submit" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button_Submit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="ButtonClickSubmit"
            android:text="@string/submit"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.775"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/Button_Clear" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

If I add this line `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent">` to the `AppBarLayout`, I can scroll to see all of the content, even the buttons. But then the included content is shown above the `AppBar`/`Toolbar`, and the `Toolbar` is gone.

To sum up, my layout is scrollable, but the bottom two buttons are cut out. The grey scrollbar at the right edge of the screen keeps going "under" / "past" the screen, when scrolling to the bottom.

Any ideas to how I can improve my code?

Comment: Just a quick question, in your activity_first_content layout, where is your TextView_Stars element which you've mentioned in your RatingBar

Comment: That layout file is HUGE, so I just cut out a lot of the content. I know the code may not make much sense now, but the content of the file wasn't important. The layout works correctly, just not the scrolling

Comment: In your top-level XML file, your `<include>` tag uses a `wrap_content` height. Does it work if you change that to `0dp` and add `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` ?

Comment: I have tried that, but then the whole content layout disappears...

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time playing around with the layouts that you posted, and I can reproduce your original problem as well as the issue with a totally disappearing layout if you add a bottom constraint to the include.

I was unable to solve the problem while maintaining a `ConstraintLayout` as the top-level view, but the problem is easy enough to solve if you switch that to a `LinearLayout` instead. Then you can have a layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".StartScreens.Home.HomeScreens.FirstActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/Activity_AppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:id="@+id/Activity_Toolbar"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/activity_first_content"
        android:id="@+id/Activity_First_Content_Include"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</LinearLayout>
```